# Frankenstein code: error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I've only been working on this for two days- I am making a form for my coworkers to add info to a database. That I knew how to do- We realized that we needed to check for the Rack, Box, and position for duplicates. If all three of those are found- in that order (i.e. Rack 1, box 2, position 3) then that means that position is taken. So we want to make sure that doesn't happen- Which I don't actually know how to do- I've been trying to use other peoples examples for a Frankenstein code I stuck in there, but its not working. Not surprisingly- my Knowledge of VBA is very basic.

I get an error code 1004.

Here is the code for the button that saves the info to the sheet.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'declare
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ctl As Control
Dim dRec As String
Dim answer As Integer
Dim dRow As Long 'duplicate row

Set ws = Worksheets("Primer Organization")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'check for a sequence
 If Trim(Me.txtSequence.Value) = "" Then
  Me.txtSequence.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please enter a proper Sequence."
  Exit Sub
End If
iRowCount = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row


'***Error code here***
'concentrate the three tested fields
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("B3", ws.Cells(iRowCount, 4)), dRec) > 0 Then
'***

'if a duplicate is found assign its location to dRow
     dRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(dRec, ws.Range("D:D"), False)
'Message to user
    answer = MsgBox("Duplicate Entry Found." & Chr(10) & "Do you want to o verwrite?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Duplicate Found")

'if it's a yes
    If answer = vbYes Then
    'if user says yes copy to sheet
    'copy the data to the database/primer Table
    With ws

.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txtFreezer.Value
.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.txtRack.Value
.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.txtBox.Value
.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.txtPosition.Value
.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.txtOligo.Value
.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.txtOligoName.Value
.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.txtSequence.Value
.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.txtSpecies.Value
.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Me.txtGene.Value
.Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Me.txtAssay.Value
.Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Me.txtConc.Value
.Cells(iRow, 12).Value = Me.txtSource.Value
.Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Me.txtPur.Value
.Cells(iRow, 14).Value = Me.txtDate.Value
.Cells(iRow, 15).Value = Me.txtName.Value
.Cells(iRow, 16).Value = Me.txtUsername.Value
.Cells(iRow, 17).Value = Me.txtNotes.Value
.Cells(iRow, 18).Value = Me.txtTags.Value

 MsgBox "Primer Added To database. Yay!"
End With
Else
If answer = vbNo Then
Exit Sub

End If
End If
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: What does 'it's not working' in detail mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Sorry The error was in the title, Ill edit my post accordingly. I get errror 1004

Comment: What line throws the error? When it happens, click "Debug" and it should yellow highlight the non-working line.

Comment: You may add some other relevant info like the line throwing the error and an example of input and desired output

Comment: Sorry I added it as comment into the code. I will remove it from the 'code' portion and highlight it

Comment: Where do you declare `iRowCount`?

Comment: Oh youre totally correct- I never did. Added to it- I am continuing to her the error, but I'll be honest im not understanding this 100%

Answer (score 0):

`drec` has not been set a value, resulting in `countif([Range],"")`. You can't look for nothing.

I haven't seen anything that explicitly says this is wrong, but all examples I have seen have something definitive for the criteria.

You could always `COUNTBLANK` if you need to.

Comment: hrm ill have to learn about countblank- My issue is that it has to be the combination of three columns together need to be ckecked- and thats throwing me off

Also youre right- i need to declare it- not i just need to learn how to declare it as all three  lol

Comment: @CelesMeh: Not just enough to declare a variable, you have to assign it a meaningful value, where "meaningful" depends on what you want your code to do.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a helper function to check each database record columns B, C and D to match corresponding textboxes entries and if match found return True along with duplicate record row index

```
Function IsPositionHeld(dataRng As Range, rack As String, box As String, position As String, dRow As Long) As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In dataRng.Columns(1).Cells 'loop through passed range first column cells
        If cell.Value = rack And cell.Offset(, 1) = box And cell.Offset(, 2) = position Then ' if duplicated record
            IsPositionHeld = True 'return True
            dRow = cell.row ' store the duplicated record row index
            Exit Function ' end the search
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

and your main sub could exploit it as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'declare
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim answer As Integer
    Dim iRow As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Primer Organization")

    With Me
        'check for a sequence
        If Trim(.txtSequence.Value) = "" Then
            .txtSequence.SetFocus
            MsgBox "Please enter a proper Sequence."
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'find first empty row in database
        iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).row + 1

        'search for any record with same Rack, Box and Position entries and if found, ask user if to overwrite
        If IsPositionHeld(ws.Range("B3", ws.Cells(iRow - 1, 4)), .txtRack, .txtBox, .txtPosition, iRow) Then _
            If MsgBox("Duplicate Entry Found at row " & iRow & Chr(10) & "Do you want to overwrite?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Duplicate Found") = vbNo Then Exit Sub


        'if user says yes copy to sheet
        'copy the data to the database/primer Table
        ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Resize(, 18).Value = _
        Array(.txtFreezer.Value, _
             .txtRack.Value, _
             .txtBox.Value, _
             .txtPosition.Value, _
             .txtOligo.Value, _
             .txtOligoName.Value, _
             .txtSequence.Value, _
             .txtSpecies.Value, _
             .txtGene.Value, _
             .txtAssay.Value, _
             .txtConc.Value, _
             .txtSource.Value, _
             .txtPUR.Value, _
             .txtDate.Value, _
             .txtName.Value, _
             .txtUserName.Value, _
             Me.txtNotes.Value, _
             .txtTags.Value)

        MsgBox "Primer Added To database. Yay!"
    End With
End Sub
```

Another option for `IsPositionHeld()` function would be `Autofilter()`:

```
Function IsPositionHeld2(dataRng As Range, rack As String, box As String, position As String, dRow As Long) As Boolean
    With dataRng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=rack
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=box
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=position
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1)) > 1 Then
            IsPositionHeld2 = True
            dRow = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Cells(1, 1).row
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Function
```

and in such a case you would pass headers row too

```
    If IsPositionHeld2(ws.Range("B2", ws.Cells(iRow - 1, 4)), .txtRack, .txtBox, .txtPosition, iRow) Then _
        If MsgBox("Duplicate Entry Found at row " & iRow & Chr(10) & "Do you want to overwrite?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Duplicate Found") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer solved your question then you may consider marking it as accepted. Thank you